# Inserting dynamic most recent date in a plot (R)

Tags: r, plot

I gather the following data. In the plot, I would like to have a heading that says "most recent date: xxxx". (dynamic) Does anyone have a solution? Open for other ideas with similar outcome to show the most recent date on the plot.Thank you!

```
library(fImport)
library(zoo)
sentiment <- fredSeries("UMCSENT", from = "1995-01-04", to = "2017-01-01")
sp500 <- fredSeries("SP500", from = "1995-01-04", to = "2017-01-01")

plot(sentiment, type = "l", col = "Orange", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", 
     main = "Uni. Michigan Consumer Sentiment vs. SP500")
axis(2)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(sp500, , type = "l", col = "red", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", ylab = "")
axis(4)
mtext("SP500", side = 4, line = 3)
legend("bottomleft", col = c("Orange", "red"), lty = 1, 
       legend = c("Sentiment (Left)", "SP500 (Right)"))
```

**Insert the most recent date (not working): (see comment section)**

```
mtext(paste("Most Recent Data", 
      index(sentiment$UMCSENT)[dim(sentiment)[1]]), cex = 1, line = 0)
```

Comment: can you edit your question and post what this command return: `index(sentiment$UMCSENT)[dim(sentiment)[1]]`

Comment: Also include what `libraries` you are using to make the example reproducible

Comment: @Jimbou this line I attempted to use in regards to a data.frame - I merely posted it to show what I am looking for. If you run the entire posted code, you get an mtext on the plot "Most Recent Data 255" I am looking to replace 255 with the most recent date. I am not even sure if this is the correct approach. Thanks,

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal "fImport" and "zoo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the information in the sub title below the plot:

```
title(sub = paste("Most Recent Data", index(sentiment$UMCSENT)[dim(sentiment)[1]]))
```

---

**Update**

After re-reading the comments, I think your issue is how to extract the date from your data. I am not familiar with `timeSeries`, but would

```
 title(sub = paste("Most Recent Data", tail(rownames(sentiment), 1)))
```

do the trick? Now you can decide whether you want to use `mtext` or `title`. This gives you the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is the date you want you need to look at the structure of `sentiment`

```
Time Series:          
Name:               object
Data Matrix:        
 Dimension:          255 1
 Column Names:       UMCSENT
 Row Names:          1995-02-01  ...  2016-04-01
Positions:          
 Start:              1995-02-01
 End:                2016-04-01
With:               
 Format:             %Y-%m-%d
 FinCenter:          GMT
 Units:              UMCSENT
 Title:              Time Series Object
 Documentation:      Mon May 23 09:59:47 2016
```

Here we see that the dates are within in the `row.names` of the object.

Thus add the following to your code to get the latest `date`

```
title(sub = paste("Most Recent Data", row.names(sentiment)[nrow(sentiment)]))
```